# What is the fastest way to load a big 2D int array from a file?

Tags: java, performance

I'm loading a 2D array from file, it's 15,000,000 * 3 ints big (it will be 40,000,000 * 3 eventually). Right now, I use `dataInputStream.readInt()` to sequentially read the ints. It takes ~15 seconds. Can I make it significantly (at least 3x) faster or is this about as fast as I can get?

Comment: Think about how the array is laid out in memory. Memory is 1D...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm buffering of course :)

Comment: 40 mil * 3 ints * 4 bytes per int = 480 MB. How fast can your drive read so much data?

Comment: @Lyth sorry, it's 15 mil (179 MB), it will be 40 mil after I download all of the data, I updated the question.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `MappedByteBuffer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** From [benchmark of 13 different ways of reading files](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly):

If you have to pick the fastest approach, it would be one of these:

- `FileChannel` with a `MappedByteBuffer` and array reads.
- `FileChannel` with a direct `ByteBuffer` and array reads.
- `FileChannel` with a wrapped array `ByteBuffer` and direct array access.

For the best Java read performance, there are 4 things to remember:

- **Minimize I/O operations by reading an array at a time, not a byte at
  a time.** An 8 KB array is a good size (that's why it's a default value for  `BufferedInputStream`).
- **Minimize method calls by getting data an array at a time, not a byte
  at a time.** Use array indexing to get at bytes in the array.
- **Minimize thread synchronization locks if you don't need thread
  safety.** Either make fewer method calls to a thread-safe class, or use
  a non-thread-safe class like `FileChannel` and `MappedByteBuffer`.
- **Minimize data copying between the JVM/OS, internal buffers, and
  application arrays.** Use `FileChannel` with memory mapping, or a direct
  or wrapped array `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 7):

Map your file into memory!

Java 7 code:

```
FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("/path/to/file"), 
    StandardOpenOption.READ);
ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(0, channel.size(),
    FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY);

// use buf
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for more details.

If you use Java 6, you'll have to:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("/path/to/file", "r");
FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
// same thing to obtain buf
```

You can even use `.asIntBuffer()` on the buffer if you want. And you can read only what you actually need to read, when you need to read it. *And* it does not impact your heap.

Comment: This is a great answer too, upvoted, if I could accept two answers I would.